# How do i get Selenium script to connect to chrome using javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm having trouble connecting to a site via Chrome, I already installed the chromedriver, and followed the instructions from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

is there anything that I'm missing?

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
build();
```

When I try this using node "filename" I get an:

```
goog.global.setTimeout(function() { throw exception; }, 0);
Error: Server terminated early with status 1
```

any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Where you have put ChromeDriver? I mean at which path?

Comment: I have it under the path that I that I'm running the command on which is /usr/src

Comment: Do you using node.js also?

Comment: yes, i used node "file name"